# How to create sortable data view in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I follow this example: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.SortingPage?0

and this is my code:

```
    SortablePlayerDataProvider dp = new SortablePlayerDataProvider();
    final DataView<Player> dataView = new DataView<Player>("rows", dp, 10) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final Item<Player> listItem) {
            final Player player = listItem.getModelObject();
            listItem.setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<Player>(player));
            listItem.add(new Label("name", player.getName()));
            listItem.add(new Label("surname", player.getSurname()));
            listItem.add(new Label("club", player.getClub()));
        }
    };
```

and provider:

```
public class SortablePlayerDataProvider extends SortableDataProvider<Player> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SortablePlayerDataProvider() {
        setSort("surname", SortOrder.ASCENDING);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Player> iterator(int first, int count) {
        return tournamentService.getAllPlayer().subList(first, first + count).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return tournamentService.getAllPlayer().size();
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<Player> model(final Player object) {
        return new LoadableDetachableModel<Player>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected Player load() {
                return object;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

but sorting doesn work and I dont know why. What is wrong ? Is there som optins how to debug it ?

UPDATE:

can someone explain me and show where is this dataProvider sorting items ?

because when I print it:

```
    Iterator<Player> a = dp.iterator(0, dp.size());
    for (Iterator<Player> iterator = a; iterator.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

items are still no sorted and when I looking for implementation of this provider I cant find where is this iterator sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found it why is doesnt work. In wicket example items are sorting when you defined iterator:

```
     return getContactsDB().find(first, count, getSort()).iterator();
```

but I dont understand why I need to sort item. Then I can create just trivial  new IDataProvider sort item when I am creating iterator and it is sorted too. This class is really obscure...

Comment: Usually, sorting and paging are responsibilities of your service/DAO class, that's why the DataProvider does not do it for you. The SortableDataProvider simply provides fields to store the sort criteria. I do not know where your data comes from, but probably more often than not web apps retrieve lists from a database - if the sorting were to be done by Java this would mean that the application always needed to load all records from the DB in order to do so and then discard all but the ones needed to display. This might work for some, but it is not scalable at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've seethe code of the example above. Maybe you may need to use component OrderByBorder

UPDATE

Data sorting should be performed by your datasource, SortableDataProvider won't do it by its own. If you look at example code you can see that it uses ContactsDatabase as datasource. This class keep two sorted list, one for the 'name' and one for the 'last name' property.

Comment: this just change sort but if this doesnt work then changing sort dont work too